# Is there a limit to the number of javascript functions per HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

I have a HTML5 file that contains javascript (made from coffeescript) directly in the HTML file (I prefer to do my HTML/js programming that way). There are four JS functions that convert one temperature unit to another. The code will not display any output. However, if the fourth function (r2k()) is deleted, all of the input boxes (except the fourth) now work. I do not know if there is an error in r2k() that I overlooked or if there is some function limitation in JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><title>Temperature Conversions</title></head>
<!--Made by Devyn Collier Johnson <DevynCJohnson@Gmail.com> (2013); Javascript made with Coffeescript-->
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function k2c() { //Kelvin to Celsius
    var x;
    x = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="k2c_input"]')[0].value) - 273.15;
    alert(x.toFixed(2));
}

function c2k() { //Celsius to Kelvin
    var x;
    x = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="c2k_input"]')[0].value) + 273.15;
    alert(x.toFixed(2));
}

function f2k() { //Fahrenheit to Kelvin
    var x;
    x = (parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="f2k_input"]')[0].value) + 459.67) * (5 / 9);
    alert(x.toFixed(2));
}

function r2k() { //Rankine to Kelvin
    var x;
    x = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="r2k_input"]')[0].value * (5 / 9);
    alert(x.toFixed(2));
}

        </script>

<h1>Temperature Conversions</h1><h6>Made by Devyn Collier Johnson &lt;DevynCJohnson@Gmail.com&gt; (2013)</h6>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return false">

<p>Kelvin to Celsius</p>
    <input type="text" name="k2c_input" value="" placeholder="KELVIN" id="k2c_input"/>
    <button name="k2c_button" id="k2c_button" onClick="k2c()">Solve</button>

<p>Celsius to Kelvin</p>
    <input type="text" name="c2k_input" value="" placeholder="CELSIUS" id="c2k_input"/>
    <button name="c2k_button" id="c2k_button" onClick="c2k()">Solve</button>

<p>Fahrenheit to Kelvin</p>
    <input type="text" name="f2k_input" value="" placeholder="FAHRENHEIT" id="f2k_input"/>
    <button name="f2k_button" id="f2k_button" onClick="f2k()">Solve</button>

<p>Rankine to Kelvin</p>
    <input type="text" name="r2k_input" value="" placeholder="RANKINE" id="r2k_input"/>
    <button name="r2k_button" id="r2k_button" onClick="r2k()">Solve</button>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><input type="reset" value="Clean Boxes"/>

</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @PaulOsborne, thank you for catching that.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if there is a limit, it's more than 3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always check your JS console. This line is missing a parenthesis:

```
x = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="r2k_input"]')[0].value * (5 / 9);
                                                                          ^
```

If you're just getting the first element matched by your selector, use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="r2k_input"]').value
```

Also, pass a radix argument to `parseInt`. Without that, numbers with leading zeroes will be interpreted as octals by some browsers:

```
parseInt(..., 10);
```

Comment: Wow! The JS code works and my code looks and runs much better! Thank you.

Comment: I cannot accept this answer until nine minutes pass, or so says the server. I will accept this answer.